# Execute a function on first startup only

Tags: python

How to - let a function run only on the first startup?
I have tried creating a value-adding mechanism (adding 1 to a variable after startup) but I failed.

```
result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "MachineGuid")
ID = str(result)

licence_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\read.txt'

oon = 0

def first_time_open_only():
    file = open(licence_path, 'w')
    file.write(ID[2:38])
    file.close()
    onn = 1 + onn

first_time_open_only()

with open(licence_path) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    if contents == str:
        pass
    else:
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If the answer i wrote has solved your problem, can you please accept and mark it as the answer?

Comment: @YOLO It's not working as I intended it to.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that can solve this problem. On each run of the code, in order to understand that a function is run before or not, is to save the flag to a file such as `pickle` or a database. The code below shows a simple example such that the function only runs one time. This kind of problems can be solved by saving the file in order to let the code know the previous state.
In this code, if it is the first run of program, the `Flag.pkl` would not exists, so the flag will be equal to zero and the function will run, but in second execution the flag will have 1 as its value and the function would not execute.

```
import pickle
import os.path
 
def runOnce():
    print("first time of execution")
    flag = 1
    with open('./Flag.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(flag, f)
        

if os.path.isfile('./Flag.pkl'):
    with open('./Flag.pkl','rb') as f:
        flag = pickle.load(f)
else:
    flag = 0
    


if flag ==0:
    runOnce()
else:
    print("This function has been executed before!")
```

Comment: But, If someone takes the python file into another PC and runs it. It won't work because here, your storing the data locally

Comment: I highly Appreciate your efforts, thankyou.

Comment: @ANONYMOUSGAMER Yes you are right if the saved file is not in same place with python file it wont work. In my mind these kind of problems can be solved by saving data to a file or database. Other solution can be saving a file to an online storage account or anything that can be accessed from every where

Comment: True, but I wanted to create an offline licensing system.